# Inserting data in postgres using a python list

Tags: python, postgresql

I want to enter a python list into an insert query and enter data into postgres, I am using executemany but still getting an error "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

```
twitter_data = ['eOc6ZEQiNCo', u'TYihcUfotnM', u'7vneoA-vY8U', '73RRIEXsdyE']    
query = "INSERT INTO videograbber (video_id) VALUES (%s)"   
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO videograbber (video_id) VALUES (%s)",[twitter_data])
con.commit()
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here

Comment: What error/problem are you getting?

Comment: I am getting this error- TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list must be a list of *tuples*.

You haven't shown what the value of `twitter_data` is, but I suspect it's a string.

You want something like:

```
twitter_data = [ ('video_id_1',), ('video_id_2',) ]
```

Note the trailing commas, making these 1-tuples, instead of just parentheses around an expression. This is a 2-element list of 1-tuples containing `(str)`, so when psycopg2 iterates the tuples within the list it gets the expected one element per tuple.

If you just wrote `[ ('video_id_1'), ('video_id_2') ]`, you'd be producing a 2-element list containing two `str` objects. These are iterable, so `psycopg2` will attempt to iterate them, converting each *character* as a a query parameter. It will have fewer parameters than characters, so it'll produce the error you showed.

You can convert a list of `str` into a list of 1-tuples of `str` with a list comprehension, e.g.:

```
twitter_data_tuples = [ (x,) for x in twitter_data ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `"INSERT INTO videograbber (video_id) VALUES (%s)"`, but `%s` is a formatting tag. Should be something like `"INSERT INTO videograbber (video_id) VALUES (?)"`